# Lodash get leafs from the mixed arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

Let me first show you the code and then I'll explain my needs. I want to show you the structure of the input array and the desired result:

```
[
  {
    link: "someurl",
    name: "Foo",
    subCats: [
      {
        link: "anotherurl",
        name: "Bar",
        subCats: [
          {
            link: "anotherurl",
            subCats: [
              {
                link: "onemorekink"
                name: "Prod",
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        link: "someurll",
        name: "Fuzzy",
        subCats: [
          {
            link: "besturiever",
            name: "SomeName",
            subCats: [
              {
                link: "onemore",
                name: "Aloc",
                subCats: [
                  {
                    link: "anotherlink"
                    name: "Final",
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And what do I need to get in the result:

```
{
  link: "onemorekink"
  name: "Prod",
},
{
  link: "anotherlink"
  name: "Final",
}
```

I hope you get the idea. Basically I need to somehow get the last `subCats` element that does not include child `subCats` and append to the resulting array.
I tried using Lodash cause it is perfect for array/object operations. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: there is something wrong in your example output and your description below that output e.g.  your input not contains string `onemorekink` (but your output does)

Comment: Deepest apologies, fixing!

Comment: Fixed typos. Now it should be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let b=[]; // result here
let f = x => x.map( y=> y.subCats ? f(y.subCats) : b.push(y) );
f(a);
```

```js
let a = [
  {
    link: "someurl",
    name: "Foo",
    subCats: [
      {
        link: "anotherurl",
        name: "Bar",
        subCats: [
          {
            link: "anotherurl",
            subCats: [
              {
                link: "onemorekink",
                name: "Prod",
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        link: "someurll",
        name: "Fuzzy",
        subCats: [
          {
            link: "besturiever",
            name: "SomeName",
            subCats: [
              {
                link: "onemore",
                name: "Aloc",
                subCats: [
                  {
                    link: "anotherlink",
                    name: "Final",
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

let b=[];
let f = x => x.map( y=> y.subCats ? f(y.subCats) : b.push(y) );
f(a);

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight forward to write a method that will do that for you without the need for lodash

```
function findLastLeafs(items, key) {
  let results = [];
  items.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item[key] && item[key].length) {
      results = results.concat(findLastLeafs(item[key], key));
    } else if (index === items.length - 1) {
      results.push(item);
    }
  })
  return results;
}

const result = findLastLeafs(data, 'subCats');
```

Answer (score 1):

pretty straight, no lodash is needed. recursive function..

```
function process(data){
        for(let a of data){
            if(a.subCats){
                process(a.subCats);
            }else{
                console.log(a)
            }
        }
    }
```